# `mklink /j` with some files ignored

Tags: windows-10, onedrive, mklink

I use this command to backup files in OneDrive

```
mklink /j "path_in_onedrive" "path_to_backup"
```

Sometimes there are huge files in `path_to_backup` that I donot need, is there a way work like `.gitignore` or `files.exclude`?

Comment: How about moving the larger files to a different folder that won't be backed up, like _TMP_ .

Comment: Some of it generated automatically and distribute irregularly.

Comment: In Windows-10 `mklink` makes shortcuts. do you need help with not making shortcuts?

Answer (score 0):

Windows 10 64-bit

How to backup all files less than 1283067904 bytes (1.19GB) in size in the current folder and all subfolders with robocopy with or without spaces in the path.

```
robocopy /s "source drive:\path" "destination drive:\path" /max:1283067904
```

If you want your backup to be an exact copy of your source (delete destination files/dirs that no longer exist in source). The `/s` option is no longer needed.  `/mir` uses the `/e` option.:

```
robocopy "source drive:\path" "destination drive:\path" /max:1283067904 /mir
```

MB to bytes 1MB x 1048576 = bytes

GB to bytes 1GB x 1073741824 = bytes

SEE robocopy /?

How to do the same thing with FORFILES.

```
FORFILES /S /C "cmd /c if @fsize lss 1283067904 xcopy /i @file \"path-to-backup folder with whitespace in the space\\\"
```

SEE forfiles /?

Comment: `mklink /j` will sync modification from `source\path` to `destination\path`, can `robocopy` or `forfiles` make it?

Comment: @ani [mklink /j](https://www.2brightsparks.com/resources/articles/NTFS-Hard-Links-Junctions-and-Symbolic-Links.pdf)

Comment: @ani Make what? read forfiles /? and robocopy /? to see it makes "it".